# How can I select a virtual attribute in a subquery with Ecto / Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

The `job` schema looks something like this:

```
schema "jobs" do
  # more fields and associations
  field :fulfilled, :boolean, virtual: true
end
```

I have the SQL I need working properly:

```
    SELECT jobs.*, (SELECT COUNT(1) = 0
            AS fulfilled
            FROM slots
            JOIN slot_groups on slots.slot_group_id = slot_groups.id
            JOIN scopes ON slot_groups.scope_id = scopes.id
            WHERE scopes.job_id = 1 AND slots.supplier_crew_member_id IS NULL)
    FROM jobs
    WHERE jobs.id = 1;
```

But converting it into `Ecto.Query` syntax is proving to be very difficult.

This is about as close as I got to it working:

```
def get_job(id) do
  Job
  |> where([j], j.id == ^id)
  |> select_merge([j], ^fulfilled(id))
  |> Repo.one()
end

defp fulfilled(job_id) do
  Api.Slots.Slot
  |> join(:inner, [slot], slot_group in assoc(slot, :slot_group))
  |> join(:inner, [slot, slot_group], scope in assoc(slot_group, :scope))
  |> where([slot, _slot_group, scope], scope.job_id == ^job_id and is_nil(slot.supplier_crew_member_id))
  |> select([_slot, _slot_group, _scope], %{fulfilled: fragment("count(1) = 0 AS fulfilled")})
end
```

but I get the following error:

```
** (ArgumentError) expected a list of fields in `select/2` inside `select`, got: `#Ecto.Query<from s0 in Api.Slots.Slot, join: s1 in assoc(s0, :slot_group), join: s2 in assoc(s1, :scope), where: s2.job_id == ^2 and is_nil(s0.supplier_crew_member_id), select: %{fulfilled: fragment("count(1) = 0 AS fulfilled")}>`
(ecto) lib/ecto/query/builder/select.ex:160: Ecto.Query.Builder.Select.fields!/2
(ecto) lib/ecto/query/builder/select.ex:177: Ecto.Query.Builder.Select.select!/5
(api) lib/api/jobs/jobs.ex:28: Api.Jobs.get_job/1
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I actually ended up figuring out what I needed. It turns out that `Subqueries are currently only supported in the from and join fields`.

I switched to using the keyword syntax and created a subquery that I joined against my outer query like so:

```
job_slots_fulfilled_query =
  from(
    from jobs in Api.Jobs.Job,
      left_join: scopes in assoc(jobs, :scopes),
      left_join: slot_groups in assoc(scopes, :slot_groups),
      left_join: slots in assoc(slot_groups, :slots),
      where: jobs.organization_id == ^org_id,
      group_by: jobs.id,
      select: %{
        id: jobs.id,
        fulfilled: fragment("every(?)", not is_nil(slots.supplier_crew_member_id))
      }
  )

Repo.all(
  from(
    j in Job,
    left_join: s in subquery(job_slots_fulfilled_query),
    on: j.id == s.id,
    where: j.organization_id == ^org_id,
    select_merge: %{fulfilled: s.fulfilled},
    preload: [:organization, :owner, :job_type, :scopes]
  )
)
```